# Quantization during phase transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory, phase-transition

Consider a scalar field $\phi(t,\vec{x})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ with the following lagrangian

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi - V(\phi)
$$

where $V(\phi)$ is such that classically we have different minima, e.g. at $\phi=0$ and $\phi= v$ where $v$ is a VEV.

If the initial condition is $\phi(t=0,\vec{x}) = 0$, the field will tunnel to the true vacuum at late times. A solution interpolating the two vacua looks like an expanding bubble that I plot for two different times $t_1 < t_2$
[image]

We usually quantize the theory at the true minimum, i.e. the one with least energy, when the transition is completed. We define one-particle states, creation/annihilation operators etc... These are the asymptotic states that enters in scattering amplitudes, and are well-defined even in the false vacuum if the tunneling time is bigger then the characteristic scattering time.

After the transition is completed, the system is entirely in the broken phase and I can describe scatterings of excitations of the field $\phi$ around the true vacuum. I am interested instead at times where the transition is not yet completed.

Consider two observers $A,B$ which stay at very large distance which can communicate through sending signals of the field $\phi$.
The observer A can locally quantize the theory, define one-particle states etc... The observer B can do the same.

I plot the system in two dimension at a given time $t_1$. The circle is the profile of the bubble, inside the field has vale $\sim v$ while outside $\sim 0$. 
[image]

**Question:** What happens around the wall of the bubble, if B and A send radially two particles? How can I describe the particles scattering?

For instance, the observer B can compute the S-matrix element $\langle p_3p_4|\mathcal{S}|p_1p_2\rangle $ where $p_i$ are the momenta of incoming and outgoing particles states, defined in the vacum of B. How can I describe the scattering between one particle coming from $B$ and another coming from $A$ which takes place near the wall of the bubble? I have no idea how to operatively study this problem.

Comment: The walls of such vacuum bubbles are usually described as being highly energetic regions that violently react with everything that passes through them. I'm not sure this problem is actually well-posed - long before the two particles have a chance to scatter with each other, they will have reacted with the rest of the mess in the wall region

Comment: @ACuriousMind thanks. Ok, so, assumed that the two particles have no chance to interact, how you would describe the interactions with the mess in the wall region?